# Incorrect event datavalue while pasting formatted data from word to Ckeditor 4 instanace

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I am using Ckeditor 4. I added an event listener (paste) that is  invoked whenever drop or paste operation is performed on the ckeditor instance.
[This is the data I am trying to paste.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTv9I.png)

The HTML data given by CKEditor has added some anchor tag with attribute name in this data, even though the original data not contain any Hyperlink.
[This is the result being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLWGr.png).

`<p style="margin-bottom:11px"><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="line-height:107%"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif"><a **name**="" href="http://www.google.com/" style="color:#0563c1; text-decoration:underline">andjsdsd</a></span></span></span></p>`

Above is the HTML obtained in the event by CkEditor. In the pasted text extra flags are being displayed because of extra name property being added in the anchor tags.

I could not find solution to this in the CKEditor  4 documentation also this is not reproducible when i try to paste in CKEditor 4 offical website demo . Is there any way to disable this anchor tag in the configuration file of ckeditor 4?

On pasting a hyperlink or even any other data, extra Anchor tag  property should not be added in event from ckeditor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.